# How to make a draggable video chat container?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a video chat container which contains video of the local user as well as a remote user. I managed to make it draggable using react-draggable but it takes unnecessary space in the DOM which is not required because it is a draggable element.

```
<Draggable nodeRef={this.draggableRef}>
    <div className={styles.remote} ref={this.draggableRef}>
        <video className={styles.remoteVideo} ref={this.remoteRef}></video>
        <div className={styles.local}>
            <video className={styles.localVideo} ref={this.localRef}></video>
        </div>
    </div>
</Draggable>
```

CSS:

```
.remote {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.local {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.remoteVideo, .localVideo {
  width: 100%;
}
```

It is expected that the container does not occupy DOM space.
What should be the recommended CSS properties to be used to achieve this?

Comment: put a `position: absolute` on it and it won't conflict with other elements. You should also put `z-index` to a high number so it always stays on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved. Refer to the following code if anybody is having the same issue:

```
.outer {
  position:absolute;
  width:17%;
  height:auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.remote {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}

.local {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 35%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer to your question.